# How do I print triangles in Java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java. I'm using Deitel and Deitel to learn Java, and one of the questions in the exercises requires you to print triangles. Here is the question:

> (Triangle Printing Program) Write an application that displays the following patterns separately, one below the other. Use for loops to generate the patterns. All asterisks (*) should be printed by a single statement of the form `System.out.print( '*' );` which causes the asterisks to print side by side. A statement of the form `System.out.println();` can be used to move to the next line. A statement of the form System.out.print( ' ' );` can be used to display a space for the last two patterns. There should be no other output statements in the program.
>
> ```
> (a)   (b)        (c)   (d)
> * ********** ********** *
> ** ********* ********* **
> *** ******** ******** ***
> **** ******* ******* ****
> ***** ****** ****** *****
> ****** ***** ***** ******
> ******* **** **** *******
> ******** *** *** ********
> ********* ** ** *********
> ********** * * **********
> ```

I got a, but I need some help with b,c and d. Thanks in advance! :)

P.S. Here's my code for a:

```
public class p5_15
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        int line;
        int star;

        for( line = 1; line <= 10; line++ )
        {
            for( star = 1; star <= line; star++ )
            {
                System.out.print( "*" );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code of (a) and (b), and you'll likely get help. Otherwise you'll be closed.

Comment: But it's the same as (a) and (b), in reverse order...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't get b either by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a for loop nested in another for loop. The syntax would look something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
       ...
```

Depending on the triangle you wish to draw, you need to play with the expression replaced by `...` as well as the initialization and condition of the 2nd for loop.

For example, in (c), on the first line (i=0) you want j to start at 0 and increment to 9 (ie the number of stars you print - 1). Then the next line (i=1), you want j to start at 0 and increment to 8. Already you should be noticing a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of people here who could code you the answer in 5 minute.  But I don't think that is going to help you.

So here is a Hint about how >>you<< could go about solving this yourself.

- Take each line in the required output, and count how many stars and spaces there are.  For example, the first line consists of "1 star, 1 space, 9 stars, 1 space, 9 stars, one space and 1 star".
- Look for a pattern in the successive lines.
- Figure out how to output the ith line, based on the pattern you have deduced and the instructions in the problem statement.
- Figure out how to output all the the lines.

This exercise is all about `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out :)